# stay login all of time in application, and when I close the app, restart, shut down mobile etc. using Http in Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, nativescript, stay-logged-in

I want to stay login in my app, only when I click log out from system I want to disconnect the connection.

Any idea please?

For login in system I used this code:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    LoginForm: FormGroup;
    loading: boolean = false;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private loginservice: LoginService, private router: Router) {
        this.LoginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ["", Validators.required],
            password: ["", Validators.required]
        });
    }
    public ngOnInit() {
    }

    login() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.loginservice.loginByUsernameAndPassword(
            this.LoginForm.controls['username'].value,
            this.LoginForm.controls['password'].value
        )
            .subscribe(
                result => {
                       if (result === true) {
                        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
                    } else {
                        this.loading = false;
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

An this code for service.ts

```
  public loginByUsernameAndPassword(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('username', username);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
    let LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.Login_mobile), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        console.log('res')
        console.log(res)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0 && res.Token) {
          this.currentUser = {
            username: username,
            token: res.Token
          }
          LS.getItem(LoginService.CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
          Toast.makeText('Authentificate successfully').show();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }));
  }

  public logout(): void {
    let LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
    LS.removeItem(LoginService.CURRENT_USER);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
```

Can you suggest me, any idea how to implement to stay login all of time in application, and when I close the app, restart, shut down mobile etc. I want to disconnect from app only when I click logout.

I'm need your suggestion please.

Comment: Mh, I believe an auto-login is what you are looking for. When the user do the login you save his data in the localStorage. So you can try to, before all, check if the localstorage has an user in it, and if it's the case do an autologin or just setup some global var that you can use in your app

Comment: Can you write any example please?